# MySQL Procedure to transform key/value pair to columns

Tags: mysql

We are trying to build a de-normalised version of our database for use in Tableau. One of the challenges we have is dealing with our key/value pairs in one of our tables. See the following simplified version of some data.

```
Asset Table
Asset ID  Site ID   Make          Model
1         1         Toyota        Corolla
2         2         Honda         Civic
3         2         Suzuki        Swift

Asset Property Types Table
Site ID  Asset Property Name    Asset Property Type
1        Odometer               Numeric
1        Registration           Text
1        Expiry Date            Date
2        Odometer               Numeric
2        Registration           Text
2        Expiry Date            Date
2        Colour                 Text


Asset Properties Table
Asset ID  Key            Text Value   Numeric Value    Date Value
1         Odometer                    1234  
1         Registration   ABC123  
1         Expiry Date                                  2018-02-08  
2         Odometer                    1255  
2         Registration   ABC124
2         Colour         Red 
2         Expiry Date                                  2018-01-08  
3         Registration   ABC125
3         Odometer                    1266
3         Colour         Blue
3         Expiry Date                                  2018-03-25
```

Some points to note on this. This is a simplified version of the data. Not all Assets will have the same key/value pairs. Sites will have individual data types that they want to store which may be different to other sites.

Ultimately here is what we want to try and achieve:

```
Site 1 Asset Table
Asset ID   Make        Model    Odometer     Registration   Expiry Date
1          Toyota      Corolla  1234         ABC123         2018-02-08

Site 2 Asset Table
Asset ID   Make        Model    Odometer     Registration   Expiry Date   Colour
2          Honda       Civic    1255         ABC124         2018-01-08    Red
3          Suzuki      Swift    1266         ABC125         2018-03-25    Blue
```

My general approach to this was the following:

1. Create the Site Specific Asset Tables with just the Make & Model and populate them.
2. Use a loop to ALTER the table adding a column for each of the Asset Properties that exist
3. Populate the Site Specific Asset table with the Asset Property data in the appropriate columns

I was hoping to do all of this with a MySQL Procedure so that I can schedule it to run automatically every hour and replace the various Site level tables. A CASE statement will not work as this needs to be dynamic.

I really appreciate any advice/help on how to achieve this. Whilst I'm okay with SQL, procedures are way out of my depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difficult bit is building dynamic case statements. So given your data (with some changes to remove white spaces and possible key word clashes)

```
create table Asset(Asset_ID int, Site_ID int,  Make varchar(20), Model varchar(20));
insert into asset values
(1  ,       1  ,       'Toyota' ,       'Corolla'),
(2  ,       2  ,       'Honda'  ,       'Civic'),
(3  ,       2  ,       'Suzuki' ,       'Swift');

drop table if exists Asset_Property_Types;
create table Asset_Property_Types (Site_ID int, Asset_Property_Name varchar(100),   Asset_Property_Type varchar(100));
insert into asset_property_types values
(1   ,    'Odometer'       ,        'Numeric_value'),
(1   ,    'Registration'   ,        'Text_value'),
(1   ,    'Expiry_Date'    ,        'Date_value'),
(2   ,    'Odometer'       ,        'Numeric_value'),
(2   ,    'Registration'   ,        'Text_value'),
(2   ,    'Expiry_Date'    ,         'Date_value'),
(2   ,    'Colour'         ,         'Text_value');


create table Asset_Properties(Asset_ID  int , asset_property_name varchar(30),Text_Value varchar(100),   Numeric_Value int ,   Date_Value date);
insert into asset_properties values
(1    ,     'Odometer'      , null      ,      1234  ,null),
(1    ,     'Registration'  , 'ABC123'  ,null        ,null),
(1    ,     'Expiry_Date'   , null      ,        null, '2018-02-08'),  
(2    ,     'Odometer'      , null      ,      1255  ,null),
(2    ,     'Registration'  , 'ABC124'  ,null        ,null),
(2    ,     'Colour'        , 'Red'     ,null        ,null),
(2    ,     'Expiry_Date'   , null      , null       ,'2018-01-08'),  
(3    ,     'Registration'  , 'ABC125'  ,null        ,null),
(3    ,     'Odometer'      , null      ,        1266,null),
(3    ,     'Colour'        , 'Blue'    ,null         ,null),
(3    ,     'Expiry_Date'   , null      , null        ,'2018-03-25');
```

This code

```
    set @sql = (select concat('select a.asset_id ,a.site_id,a.make,a.model,',
             group_concat(
            concat('max(case when asset_property_name  = ' ,char(39),asset_property_name,char(39), ' then ' ,asset_property_type ,' else null end) as ', asset_property_name)
            )
            ,' from asset a join asset_properties ap on ap.asset_id = a.asset_id group by a.site_id,a.asset_id;'
            )
    from 
    (select distinct asset_property_name,asset_property_type from asset_property_types) a
    )
    ;
```

builds this sql statement

```
select a.asset_id ,a.site_id,a.make,a.model,
        max(case when asset_property_name  = 'Odometer' then Numeric_value else null end) as Odometer,
        max(case when asset_property_name  = 'Registration' then Text_value else null end) as Registration,
        max(case when asset_property_name  = 'Expiry_Date' then Date_value else null end) as Expiry_Date,
        max(case when asset_property_name  = 'Colour' then Text_value else null end) as Colour 
from asset a join asset_properties ap on ap.asset_id = a.asset_id 
group by a.site_id,a.asset_id;
```

Which you can then submit to sql like so

```
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

Comment: That is so awesome P.Salmon! Just about perfect actually. One issue though. The dates are coming through as values like 323031352d30362d30312030303a30303a3030. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: What is the date type of date_value in Asset_Properties?

Comment: It is: datetime

Comment: Is it mysql or tableau that is returning these odd dates?

Comment: Still in MySQL at this stage. Haven't pointed Tableau to anything yet. That was a simplified version of the data. A fair bit more transformation to do once I get this part sorted (which you've been Uber helpful in solving!)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help maybe it's a data issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm over the biggest hurdle. I will work this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to the pivot table problem. You can google it to find further variants of solving it. One way to solve it is

A) Fetch the column names

```
`Select distinct key from assetPropertiesTable;`
```

B) Build a Select query string using dynamic SQL that, for each key k from the previous query, has a column using a subselect like

```
(select textvalue from assetPropertiesTable t where t.id = outerselect.id and key = k) as column_k
```

C) Execute the full query and either return it from the stored procedure or do a `create table xyz as /*select query here*/`.
No need to create and fill the table in two steps.

There are more distinguished and more performant ways of doing that, for example joining the assetPropertiesTable once and doing sums on boolean condition `key=k` for each column you want to add